# Foreach in foreach check data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have an xml file where I get the data. I record this data in the database and make updates. Now I am faced with a situation whose logic I cannot solve.

I want to do; I want to check the data in the database for the data I get from XML, to add if there is any unattached data and to update it if it is added.

Sample codes are as follows. Thank you in advance for your support

```
$current = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/simple.xml');

foreach($current->simple as $item){

// Database Control data
$tax  = $item->tax;
$data = $db->query("SELECT*FROM current WHERE tax_number = '$tax' ");

foreach($data->results() as $row){

if(isset($data))
{
   // Edit
}
else
{
   // Insert
}

}

}
```

According to the codes above, there is a situation like this. For example, if there are 50 data in the XML file, it returns 50 * 500 times if there is 500 data in the current table, multiplying each data by the number in the table I want to control. And he just adds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you'll have unique value per `tax_number` in your table. You should make this `tax_number` column as unique.

```
ALTER TABLE `current`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `tax_number` (`tax_number`);
```

Once done you can use mysql [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature to insert a record or update existing record in single query for a given tax_number.

Considering you have `col1`, `col2` and `tax_number` as columns in your table and you want to update `col1` if this record already exists. So mysql query would be

```
INSERT INTO `current` (col1, col2, tax_number) 
VALUES ('a', 'b', 12345)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = 'a';
```

***Note: Your code is vulnerable to `sql injection`, make sure you update your code by [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) with parameter binding.***

So corresponding code in php would be like this.

```
$current = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/simple.xml');

foreach($current->simple as $item){

    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO current (currentDocumentNumber, currentTaxNumber, currentIdentity,currentOperationType,currentAmountOfDebt,currentAmountDue,currentAccountDate)
                VALUES (:doc_number, :tax_number, :identity, :operation_type, :debt_amount, :due_amount, :date)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currentAmountOfDebt = :debt_amount, currentAmountDue = :due_amount');
   
    $query->bindParam(':doc_number', $item->EVRAK_NO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':tax_number', $item->VERGI_NO, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':identity', $item->TC_KIMLIK_NO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':operation_type', $item->ISLEM_TURU, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':debt_amount', $item->KPB_BTUT, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':due_amount', $item->KPB_ATUT, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':date', $item->TARIHI, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: i tried but it just saves, does not update. Why could it be?

Comment: Make sure you update value `a` with relevant php variables.

Comment: Can you show us the `echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); die;`. I want to see what values you have inside this variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use the codes you gave me as they are, but it just adds the data, re-registers it instead of updating even existing data.

Comment: of course you need to update these col1 or col2 as per your code that why i asked you the dump `echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); die;`

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [VERGI_NO] => 4700597764
    [KPB_ATUT] => 3.066153000000000e+004
    [EVRAK_NO] => CH21732
    [ISLEM_TURU] => 13
    [TARIHI] => 2020-03-12T19:20:11.947
) ` Even if some parameters do not appear here, there is no problem because they are variable.

Comment: Sorry, the code snippet I added to the answer doesn't work. Why could it be? Do you have an idea? It is just saving but not updating. Very strange.